# Javascript Regex to match feet inches measurement issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to regex, and I am trying to create a regular expression to match a string that holds a measurement expressed in feet and inches with the possibility of fractional values in the inches. So far, I have the following expression:

```
var rex =/\s*(\d+)?\s*(?:'|ft|ft.|feet)?\s*-?\s*(\d+)?\s*(\d+)?\/?(\d+)?\s*(?:''|"|in|in.|inches)?/
```

To be as flexible as possible I made all the captures optional to set measurements like `1ft` or `5''` as valid input data.

```
var mstring = '5in';
var match = rex.exec(mstring);
```

The problem is that when the regex is applied, for example to `5in` the capture that I get is `match[1]='5'` while the other three values (`match[2]`, `match[3]` and `match[4]`) remain `undefined`.

Is there a way that the captured values appear in the order they are defined?
In the above mentioned case, it will be that `match[2]="5in"` while `match[1]`, `match[3]` and `match[4]` remain `undefined`.

Comment: Can you list all the variants you want to match?

Comment: "1ft"     "5in"    "1ft  5in"  "1ft-5in"   "2ft 5 15/32in"  '4 7/8"'

Comment: the match in a general case wiil be "1ft 5 7/8" match[1]=1 match[2]=5 match[3]=7 match[4]=8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is in using non-capturing groups around the optional parts and using obligatory subpatterns inside those groups:

```
var rex =/(?:\s*(\d+)\s*(?:feet|ft\.|ft|'))?(?:\s*-\s*(\d+))?(?:\s*(\d+)\/)?(?:(\d+)\s*(?:inches|in\.|in|''|"))?/
```

In Group 1, I made `(?:feet|ft\.|ft|')` obligatory, in Group 2, it is the hyphen `-`, in Group 3, the slash `/`, and in Group 4, it is the `(?:inches|in\.|in|''|")` alternation.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gY7fZ6/2)

#### EDIT:

I do not understand the logic now, but if you want `5` in `5in` to appear in the 2nd group, use

```
(?:\s*(\d+)\s*(?:feet|ft\.|ft|'))?(?:\s*-?\s*(\d+))?(?:\s*(\d+)\/)?(?:(\d+)\s*(?:inches|in\.|in|''|"))?
                                         ^
```

See [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/gY7fZ6/3)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. I tested the solution with '5in' and the match occurs in the fourth position (match[4] ) while it should appear in second place (match[2])...any idea?

Comment: I am citing you: *In the above mentioned case, it will be that match[4]="5in" while match[1], match[2] and match[3] remain undefined.* So, it is in Group 4, as you asked for.

Comment: Sorry so much i mean match[2]=5, I just edit the post.

Comment: I have updated the regex, but really, I do not know what you are doing :)

Comment: I just want all the data in place to do the conversion to inches: 12*match[1]+match[2]+match[3]/match[4] avoiding problems with undefinded values if its the case...

Comment: Anyway, I hope you now understand how to force the match to go into the correct group, don't you? In my updated regex, I made the hyphen optional. When you make all parts of a non-capturing optional group optional, it won't contain any results.

Comment: Perfect. I think that I get the idea. Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

I would consider doing some pre-processing - remove all whitespace and do some conversion on the input.  For example:

```
// normalize the input, e.g. 5 feet 11 inches becomes 5'11"
// any non-numerical character sequence starting with f is considering feet measurement, similar for inches (i.e. starting with i)
text = text.replace(/[^A-Z0-9'"]*/gi, '').replace(/f[^0-9]*/, "'").replace(/i[^0-9]*/, '"');

// regexp becomes simpler
var re = /(\d+')?(\d+")?/
```